# Is there a better way to display additional information from the Django model in the Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models

Is there a better way to make the code less repetitive by moving the "CONN" to where is can still be used but where it only need to be written once. So I can still display the same information in the same fields in django admin.

When I move "CONN" somewhere else the function stops working. and an error get displayed.

Models.py

```
from .connection import HostConn

class Host(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    login = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=14, blank=True, null=True)
    conntype = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=CONN_SELECT)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def status(self):
        conn = HostConn(self.hostname, self.login, self.password, self.conntype)
        status = conn.host_up()
        return status

    def cpu(self):
        conn = HostConn(self.hostname, self.login, self.password, self.conntype)
        return conn.get_host_info()[0]

    def memory(self):
        conn = HostConn(self.hostname, self.login, self.password, self.conntype)
        return conn.get_host_info()[1]

    def free_memory(self):
        conn = HostConn(self.hostname, self.login, self.password, self.conntype)
        return conn.get_host_info()[2]
```

admin.py

```
class HostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'hostname', 'conntype', 'status', 'cpu', 'memory', 'free_memory', 'options')
```

Comment: What is `HostConn` here?

Comment: HostConn is an import ```class HostConn:
    def __init__(self, host, login, passwd, conntype): ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a `property` on your `Host` model:

```py
from .connection import HostConn

class Host(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    login = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=14, blank=True, null=True)
    conntype = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=CONN_SELECT)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def conn(self):
        return HostConn(self.hostname, self.login, self.password, self.conntype)

    def status(self):
        return self.conn.host_up()

    def cpu(self):
        return self.conn.get_host_info()[0]

    def memory(self):
        return self.conn.get_host_info()[1]

    def free_memory(self):
        return self.conn.get_host_info()[2]
```

See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) for more information about properties.

If you are worried about making unnecessary multiple calls to the `conn` function, you can memoize it using `lru_cache` for example. See [this section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) of the Python documentation for more information.

Comment: Thanks. It certainly makes the code less repetitive.